# Is it possible to manual change the WIFI link speed?

Tags: performance, wifi

In my project, I have a Android smartphone and a router (can be a normal router or use a laptop running Linux or Windows). I need to emulate some traffic jam or signal degradation. I know the WIFI link speed is normally changing automatically based on signal strength and etc..Is it possible to change it manually whenever I want?  The signal strength is always good because I just put the phone beside the router..
Thanks,

Comment: Use a combination of turning down the transmit power and putting the phone further away from the router.

Comment: @Sammitch I see... But do you know is there a way to do it in code or software?

Comment: Obviously it depends on the router.  On most 'enterprise' APs you can connect with a command line interface and issue commands to change settings, which would include radio power, frequency, maximum link speed, etc.

Comment: @Zoredache Looks useful. I will take a look at my router settings. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Since you mentioned linux.

[iwconfig man page says you can....](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/iwconfig8.html) 
eg:

```
 iwconfig wlan0 rate 11M
 iwconfig wlan0 rate auto
 iwconfig wlan0 rate 5.5M auto
```

Comment: Looks like you are configuring the ethernet. What is needed is to configure the WIFI link speed:)

Comment: No, Mike Brentlinger's comments are correct. The `iwconfig` command is specifically for Wi-Fi, and the speeds he uses in his example are for Wi-Fi (IEEE 802.11) and not for Ethernet (802.3).